# Convert array of hashes to array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes from which I need the values of the hashes in a new array. The array of hashes look likes this, with a couple thousand of them.

```
array = [{:code=>"404"}, {:code=>"302"}, {:code=>"200"}]
```

I have tried to look this up but have only found out how to convert from a hash.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Can you add what the output should be?

Comment: `array.flat_map { |h| h.values }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a=[{:code=>"404"}, {:code=>"302"}, {:code=>"200"}] 
puts a.map{|x|x.values}.flatten.inspect
```

output

```
["404", "302", "200"]
```

Comment: When I try to use this I get a undefined method for the values part. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you use the same code? Because I executed my code and pasted it here, it works fine. Which version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: I tried it in irb and it did work for me too. It must be something in my code causing it not to work. I'm using 2.3.1.

Comment: I got it to work. their was two brackets at either end because i was pushing the array in to another array.

Comment: whenever you use `map` followed by `flatten`, consider using `flat_map` instead.

Comment: instead of using `puts` with a final chained method `inspect`, simply use `p`. e.g. `p a.map { |x| x.values }.flatten`.

Comment: Yes I know that it would print the same because when we use p it automatically calls the inspect method upon the result .

Comment: @sagarpandya82 Thank you for telling me about flat_map which I am not aware of that.

Answer (score 8):

```
[{:code=>"404"}, {:code=>"302"}, {:code=>"200"}].flat_map(&:values)
#⇒ ["404", "302", "200"]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
arr =[{:code=>"404"}, {:code=>"302"}, {:code=>"200"}]

arr.map { |h| h[:code] }
  #=> ["404", "302", "200"]
```

or, if the name of the key (now `:code`) might change in future:

```
arr.map { |h| h.first.last }
  #=> ["404", "302", "200"]
```

Comment: Good one! I haven't noticed the fact that keys are equal. And also I don't know that `h.first` converts hash key,value as array.

Comment: @Gopal, that's always the case when a hash's elements (key-value pairs) are enumerated. For example, `{a: 1, b: 2}.each { |a| p a }` prints
`[:a, 1]` then `[:b, 2]`.

Comment: Yes, but what's the relation between enumeration and .first? why does .first returns array of key,value?

Comment: @Gopal, `first` is a method in the `Enumerable` module. That module is included by the class `Hash`.  All methods in `Enumerable` require that the receiver be an enumerator. When `first` is called on a hash, Ruby (after seeing that there is no method `Hash#first` and knowing that `Enumerable#first` requires an enumerator) inserts the instance method `Hash#each`: `{a: 1}.first` is evaluated as `{a: 1}.each.first`. That's why all classes that include `Enumerable` must have a method `each` that returns an enumerator.

Comment: Excellent explanation, Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: You say all the methods in Enumerable require the receiver be an enumerator, but `each` method is from enumerator class but it can be called upon array like `a.each`, but a is not an enumerator object, So it contradict with what you said, right?

Comment: @Gopal, if I write `[1,2,3].each`, that would be [Array#each](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each). See my answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40121370/why-does-chunk-while-return-enumerator-class-object/40121790#comment67521434_40121790) recent question for more on this subject.

Comment: Yeah I have already read that answer, you said that each would be inserted and I refereed the documentation for Enumerator where I found one `each`, So this confusion, Thanks.

Comment: @Gopal, thanks for pointing out how that part of my answer at the link might be misunderstood. I did an edit. I'm impressed by your dogged pursuit of a clear understanding of what's going on here. That's the only way to learn Ruby well.

Comment: Thank you very much Cary, I have been a curious reader of your answer even before I started to answer! You have such a deep knowledge in Ruby which I would like to have for myself  :)

Comment: In my case I had a list like this: `[{:id => '0', :name => 'some name'}, {:id => '2', :name => 'some name'}, {:id => '2', :name => 'some name'}]` so I solved it in this way to `time_zone_list.map { |tz| [ tz[:id], tz[:name] ] }` to have something like this `[[0, 'some name'], [1, 'some name'], [2, 'some name']]` so that I can fill in a dropdown list. Hope it could be useful for someone else. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

This question is tagged with `ruby` only.

But I think it might be worth noting that, when you happen to use Ruby on Rails or have the `activesupport` gem in your `Gemfile` anyway, then you might want to use [`Enumerable#pluck`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activesupport/Enumerable:pluck):

```
array = [{:code=>"404"}, {:code=>"302"}, {:code=>"200"}]
array.pluck(:code)
#=> ["404", "302", "200"]
```