# Why does chunk_while return Enumerator object

Tags: ruby

Why does `chunk_while` return an instance of `Enumerator`?

This code:

```
array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 15, 16]
p array.chunk_while {|i,j| i + 1 == j }
```

outputs this:

```
#<Enumerator::Generator:0x00000002bef0a8>:each>
```

I have ruby version `ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x64-mingw32]`.

Comment: Do you want to see all the elements inside the Enumerator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methods in the [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html) module, such as `chunk_while`, require that receivers be enumerators, that is, instances of the class [Enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerator.html). Therefore if an `Enumerable` method such as `chunk_while` returns an enumerator, it can be the receiver to another `Enumerable` method (and that method can be the receiver of another `Enumerable` method, and so on). This is called *method chaining*. That's why you see many `Enumerable` methods return an enumerator if no block is provided.

The chaining of methods that have enumerators as receivers may also include methods in other modules or in the class `Enumerator`, such as  [Enumerator#with_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index).

This is why we can write expressions such as the following.

```
array.chunk_while {|i,j| i + 1 == j }.map.with_index { |a,i| i.even? ? a.reduce(:+) : 0 }
  #=> [15, 0, 31]
```

Let's break this down.

```
e0 = array.chunk_while {|i,j| i + 1 == j }
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007fa01b9639e0>:each> 
e1 = e0.map
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007fa01b9639e0>:each>:map> 
e2 = e1.with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator:
  #    #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007fa01b9639e0>:each>:map>:with_index> 
e2.each { |a,i| i.even? ? a.reduce(:+) : 0 }
  #=> [15, 0, 31]
```

Examine the return values for the operations that produce `e0`, `e1` and `e2`. `e1` and `e2` may be thought of as *compound enumerators*.

As a matter of practice, `chunk_while` is almost always chained to another method, so it makes sense for it to return an enumerator.

You might well ask, "why must all enumerable methods require a receiver that is an enumerator, considering that `chunk_while`'s receiver in the example, `array`, is not an enumerator"? The answer lies in the fact that every class that includes the `Enumerable` module must have a method `each` that returns an enumerator. One therefore could write

```
array.each.chunk_while {|i,j| i + 1 == j }.to_a
```

but Ruby saves you the trouble. Ruby will invoke [Array#each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40066614/convert-array-of-hashes-to-array/40066893?noredirect=1#comment67536024_40066893) for you when it sees that the method being invoked on an array requires an enumerator as its receiver. The same is true of all classes that have a method `each`.

Comment: Or, the really short answer: because [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while) says so.