# Ruby convert array of active records or objects into array of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, hash

I have an object Persons which is an ActiveRecord model with some fields like :name, :age .etc.

Person has a 1:1 relationship with something called Account where every person has an account .

I have some code that does :

```
   Account.create!(person: current_person)
```

where current_person is a specified existing Person active record object.

Note : The table Account has a field for person_id
and both of them have has_one in the model for each other.

Now I believe we could do something like below for bulk creation :

```
 Account.create!([{person: person3},{person:: person2} ....])
```

I have an array of `persons` but am not sure of the best way to convert to an array of hashes all having the same key.

Basically the reverse of [Convert array of hashes to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40066614/convert-array-of-hashes-to-array/40067384#40067384) is what I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `create` method actually persists each hash individually, as shown in the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-0-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L29), so probably it's not what you are looking for. Either way the following code would do the job:

```rb
  Account.create!(persons.map { |person| Hash[:person_id, person.id] })
```

If you need to create all records in the same database operation and are using rails 6+ you could use the [insert_all](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods/insert_all) method.

```rb
  Account.insert_all(persons.map { |person| Hash[:person_id, person.id] })
```

For previous versions of rails you should consider using [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) gem.

```rb
  # Combination(1).to_a converts [1, 2, 3] to [[1], [2], [3]]
  Account.import [:person_id], persons.pluck(:id).combination(1).to_a
```

Comment: Thank you . This seems to be better.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just loop over your array of objects?

```
[person1, person2].each{|person| Account.create!(person: person)}
```

But if for any reason any of the items you loop over fail `Account.create!` you may be left in a bad state, so you may want to wrap this in an [Active Record Transaction](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html).

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  [person1, person2].each{|person| Account.create!(person: person)}
end
```

Comment: In my current solution I was looping over , I assumed batching might help run the queries faster which is why I want to use the bulk create API as I think it handles the transaction part you were mentioning for me ??

Comment: @PrasaanthNeelakandan what data is being written in this loop? How many records to you need to do at a clip? There are other ways to improver performance if that's your goal but that is not what you asked in your question.

Comment: I want to write about 50 entries of data together , like in batches . The writes just write one single field .